# How to handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Angular2

Tags: angular

[error-handling](https://angular.cn/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) shows how to handle errors as follows:

```
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Promise.reject(errMsg);
}
```

I'd like to access an API server, but the server hasn't started. Then I got the error:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/heroes net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I need to **tell the user politely that the API server hasn't started**. How should I handle the error?

The error Response is:

```
_body:ProgressEvent
headers:Headers
ok:false
status:0
statusText:""
type:3
url:null
```

Could I handle this according to the **status** of the response?

Comment: I also want to know why the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` can't response immediately. It sometimes happens a minute later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//First inject the router in the constructor


private handleError (error: Response | any) {
//Your other codes    

if (error.status == 0){ //or whatever condition you like to put
this.router.navigate(['/error']);
}
}
```

Comment: What does the status 0 mean? Where could I find the definition online?

Comment: A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status, other codes indicate failure. More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I know. But what's the status 0? Normally I see status 0 as success in other programming languages.

Comment: Status codes are from HTTP standard protocol and are not depending on any programming language. But, 0 is not an official HTTP status code, you got it here because your app did not hit any HTTP server.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can get status 0 for a number of other client side error including `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`,.

Answer (score 8):

It's impossible distinguish both ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (the one someone had mentioned above) and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, because HttpErrorResponse class doesn't differentiate them. So you have to use status 0 to handle all the generic errors. According to list of HTTP status codes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

> If you receive a response that is not in this list, it is a
> non-standard response, possibly custom to the server's software.

It means 0 is a non-standard response.

Angular is a Javascript Framework; hence you should refer to XMLHttpRequest status codes to find out what 0 means. The Mozilla page says..

> Before the request completes, the value of status is 0. Browsers also
> report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

So, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means the connection is not established (request is not completed), and therefore, the status code is 0. In that case it's safe to say "Unable to Connect to the Server". throwError is a RxJs function that emit error message, which you can read through Subscribe() method.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
       if (errorObj instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (errorObj.status === 0) {
          return throwError('Unable to Connect to the Server');
        }
       }
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I got similar error and the reason was quite lame.
If you're using angular and spring boot the possible reason for this type of error could be spring application is not running.
Both servers must be on.

Answer (score -8):

This happens when you try to reach an insecure https site.

A solution is : first connect to the insecure site with your browser, a warning page will display. Click on "advance parameter" and accept this site as secure. Second you can reach this destination with your Angular code.

Hope this helps.